# Item not being pushed to array in Angular class

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I made an Angular Service that keeps a list of items that other components can add items to and can retrieve. For some reason nothing gets added to the list. It does only within the add() function of my service but the variable doesn't get changed outside of it.. For example, at the end of the add() function, the console returns the item that was added. But when I check the list again from the getItems() function list is empty. Why would list doesn't get updated outside of the function after push?

```
    export class BasketService {
      private list: Item[] = [];
      constructor() {}

      add(product: Product, units: number): void {
        let item: Item = new Item();
        item.product = product;
        item.units = units;
        this.list.push(item);
        console.log(this.list[(this.list.length - 1)]);
        // Log shows item object
      }
      getItems(): Observable<Item[]> {
        console.log(this.list);
        // Log shows empty array
        return of(this.list);
      }
    }
```

**EDIT**

getItems() does have a subscriber however the issue doesn't seem to come from there since it receives an empty array of Item, the same empty list that is printed by the console in getItems (in the basketService).

```
export class BasketComponent implements OnInit {
  items: Item[];

  constructor(private basketService: BasketService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getItems();
    console.log(this.items.length);
  }
  getItems(): void {
    this.basketService.getItems()
      .subscribe(items => {
        this.items = items; });
  }
```

Comment: How do you call `getItems` ?

Comment: Seems like getItems() is only called once on subscription, and will not be updated further. Suggest you to use a rxjs Subject (or possibly a BehaviorSubject to always provide last value to subscribers), call next method every time the list is updated to inform subscribers. Them, your getItems method may return your Subject as a Observable (to avoid values to be emitted from outside your service).

Comment: Are you subscribing to the returned observable ?

Comment: Yes I'm using a subscriber, it does receive the list but it's empty (initialized but empty).

Answer (score 1):

Your `getItems()` method returns an `Observable` holding your list of items. You need to subscribe to that `Observable` to get the items.

Also, you could use a `BehaviorSubject` to push the list in the `Observable` every time the list is modified.

That way, your service consumers will get notified through the observable when there is an item added.

```
@Injectable()
export class BasketService {
  private list: Item[] = [];
  private subject = new BehaviorSubject<Item[]>([]);
  private list$ = this.subject.asObservable();

  add(product: Product, units: number): void {
    let item: Item = new Item();
    item.product = product;
    item.units = units;
    this.list.push(item);
    this.subject.next(this.list); // push the modified list to notify observers
  }
  getItems(): Observable<Item[]> {
    return this.list$;
  }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private service: BasketService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getItems().subscribe(items => {
      console.log('list modified', items); // this is executed after each list.push()
    });
  }
}
```

You could also use `scan` with a `Subject` and get rid of the `list` variable. The list will be created by the `scan` operator by appending to the previous values:

```
@Injectable()
export class BasketService {
  private subject = new Subject<Item>();
  private list$ = this.subject.pipe(
    scan((list, item) => [...list, item], [] as Item[]),
  );

  add(product: Product, units: number): void {
    let item: Item = new Item();
    item.product = product;
    item.units = units;
    this.subject.next(item);
  }
  getItems(): Observable<Item[]> {
    return this.list$;
  }
}
```

> Here is a short [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-rxjs-scan) using the scan operator.

Comment: I tried using BehaviorSubject but I'm still getting the same result. The array is staying empty

Comment: @OcnLaroche, are you subscribing to the observable ? could you share your subscription code ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your service is decorated with @Injectable and provided properly so all your components that use the service
 have the same instance of a service.

Comment: Seems that this is not related to how service is provided, but rather to how Observables and subscriptions are used. Also, the @Injectable decorator is not required, as nothing is being injected into BasketService.

Comment: @Injectable is present. The subscriptions appears to be working as well